# How to compare the relative paths two folders, subforlders and file and pass the absolute path of all the matching files to a function?

Tags: python, file, navigation

I need to compare the relative paths of two directories of similar structure and pass the absolute path of the corresponding files if the relative paths match.

```
source_path = '/home/user/Downloads/Test'
target_path = '/home/user/Downloads/SampleCode/Test'
```

`source_path` and `target_path` have similar folder structure:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1CDc.png)

I need to pass the absolute paths of all the files to the below function that checks the cryptographic hash of these files, **if and only if the relative paths match**.

```
def compare_all_files(source, target):
    """ The File comparison is done here """
```

My Code:

def match_files_from_directories(source, target) -> bool:
"""Derives the relative path and Abs path of all the directories """

```
rel_source_path_list = []  # List to store all Revative Path from Source_Path
rel_target_path_list = []  # List to store all Revative Path from Target_Path
abs_source_path_list = []  # List to store all Absolute Path from Source_Path
abs_target_path_list = []  # List to store all Absolute Path from Target_Path
rel_source_path_list_1 = []  # Some files in the Source Path has files like ".git", ".some.yml" that appear in front of file name
                            # This list strips the "." and stores the relative paths. 


for source_dirName, source_subdirList, source_fileList in os.walk(source):
    source_subdirList[:] = [d for d in source_subdirList if d not in [".git", ".idea"]]
    for file in source_fileList:
        print(file)
        source_path_files = os.path.join(source_dirName, file)
        # print("source_path_files", source_path_files)
        abs_source_path_list.append(source_path_files)
        rel_source_path = os.path.relpath(source_dirName, source) + file
        rel_source_path_list.append(rel_source_path)
        print("rel_source_path_list", rel_source_path_list)

for items in rel_source_path_list:
    items_strip = items.strip(".")
    rel_source_path_list_1.append(items_strip)
    # print("rel_source_path_list_1 :", rel_source_path_list_1)

#print("abs_source_path_list Outside for loop", abs_source_path_list)
print("rel_source_path_list Outside for loop", rel_source_path_list_1)

for target_dirName, target_subdirList, target_fileList in os.walk(target):
    target_subdirList[:] = [d for d in target_subdirList if d not in [".git", ".idea"]]
    for file in target_fileList:
        target_path_files = os.path.join(target_dirName, file)
        abs_target_path_list.append(target_path_files)
        # print("abs_target_path_list", abs_target_path_list)
        rel_target_path = os.path.relpath(target_dirName, target) + file
        rel_target_path_list.append(rel_target_path)

# print("abs_target_path_list Outside for loop", abs_target_path_list)
# print("rel_target_path_list outside for loop", rel_target_path_list)
```

match_files_from_directories(source_path, target_path)

So Here I have one list that contains all the Relative paths and one list contains all the Absolute paths. I need to match the absolute path and the relative path before passing it to another functions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the pathlib module.

```
from pathlib import Path


# sample paths
rp1 = './folder1/b.txt'  # relative
ap2 = 'f:/folder1/b.txt' # absolute
ap3 = 'f:/a/b/c/1.txt'

# Get path in Path format.
rp1_path = Path(rp1)
ap2_path = Path(ap2)

# Get the absolute path of relative path. Use absolute().
abs_rp1_path = rp1_path.absolute()

# Compare paths which are now in absolute form.
if abs_rp1_path == ap2_path:
    print('same')
else:
    print('not same')

# Get sub-folder files on `f:/a/b` of ap3.
ap3_path = Path(ap3)
cur_folder = ap3_path.cwd()
print(cur_folder.as_posix())  # f:/a/b/c

sub_cur_folder = cur_folder.parent
print(sub_cur_folder.as_posix())  # f:/a/b

for files in sub_cur_folder.glob('*.*'):
    print(files.as_posix())  # f:/a/b/q.txt f:/a/b/s.txt ...
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. How do you I do it for sub-folders and folders and files inside that Subfolders ? Please suggest.

Comment: Added sample on # Get sub-folder files on `f:/a/b` of ap3.